# Direct linking to Page in native Facebook App (iOS6)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

In iOS 5 you could open a Facebook Page in the native app by accessing fb://page/585828424 in Safari [1]

This doesn't seem to work on the iOS6 Facebook App (testing on app v.47423 on an iPhone 5).

Is there a work around or is direct linking just a retired feature?

===

[1] [Open a facebook link by native Facebook app on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios)

Also, if it's helpful, [here's a list of what was possible in iOS 5 using fb://something](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been changed to be a profile,even though a FB page is not a profile.

```
fb://profile/[your id]
```

Replace the `page` with `profile` in the link and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did the same thing but it doesn't work with the post that contains video. it goes to the Facebook app but show nothing. For example this one `10153231379946729`. Any idea?