# How to open a Facebook Timeline from iOS Application?

Tags: ios, facebook

How to open a Facebook timeline from iOS application?
I've tried this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios), for example

```
fb://profile/Google
```

and it opens my personal timeline instead. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got managed to it. Here are some steps to get it:

> 1. http://graph.facebook.com/profilename
> 2. Look for "id" and get it.
> 3. fb://profile/retrievedIdFromStep2