# Open Facebook app to customer's page?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm building an iOS app with the Facebook SDK.

One of the things my customer wants is a button that launches the Facebook app and shows their Facebook page. Is there some way to do this, perhaps using a URL?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just launch the link or open a UIWEbView with the supplied URL?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone has a bunch of URL schemes such as:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://<insert function here>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Check this site out for more:

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Also check out this SO post for more info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416399/738262