# ios can I open a facebook page in facebook app programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-like, ios6.0

I am trying to implement facebook page like in ios .I want to open page in the app and then user can like or unlike.If there is a account in settings already then it should not ask for login.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios