# Open Facebook page from iOS game

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a facebook game and I want to have a button which let user open my facebook page, however, when I open my page url:
https://www.facebook.com/Spiritbomb.co

It just opens the native Facebook app but does not redirect to my page.
I tried this url on Safari and it works just fine.
Anyone experienced with this could help me please?

Comment: you used handleopenurl to open your page? please show some code.

Comment: Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios

Comment: You want to open your page in safari? Or you want something that will display you page in the app?

Comment: The link @RajanBalana provides is extremely helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this type of url doesn't work
**https://www.facebook.com/Spiritbomb.co**
(What I mean by "doesn't work" is that open this URL in an iOS app will only launch the FB native app, but does not redirect you to the desired Page)

You need to find your Facebook Page ID and use this URL: **https://www.facebook.com/YOUR_FB_PAGE_ID**
In my case, this URL works: https://www.facebook.com/690543054295905

How to find your FB Page ID: Go to your FB Page, click Edit Page -> Update Page Info
Then scroll to the bottom of the page, you'll find your FB page ID there.

Thanks for all the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSURL

NSUrl *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your facebook url"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];