# ios Facebook custom url scheme to open user profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/user.x"]];
```

`fb://profile/[your ID]` and the facebook app will open to your page.

`fb://profile/(fbid)`

I followed the steps above to open Facebook native app in iOS 8 but it does not work, is there a way to do this?

I mean twitter works perfect whats wrong with Facebook not updating their API!.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a standard API, and has never been documented, why do you expect it to work?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to find a way to get this to work because I am finalizing a jailbreak tweak where this feature will be useful. Twitter supports this I don't understand why Facebook with all its might and glory doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ming Li pointed out in his comment, this is not officially supported. You can't deeplink to a user profile in the Facebook app.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as my comment above I am hoping to find a way because I am finalizing a jailbreak tweak where I think this will be useful.

Comment: I don't know about any reasoning or other way except what Ming Li said, it is not officially supported and you should not expect it to work