# Open Facebook application from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, url-scheme

Can someone tell the URL schemes to open the Facebook application from my app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios

some time this ink will help you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `fb://`.

`canOpenURL` returns a `BOOL` value indicating whether or not the URL’s scheme can be handled by some app installed on the device. If `canOpenURL` returns `YES` then the application is present on the device. If the user has Facebook installed on their device we open it. If the user does not have Facebook installed we open the page through a link, which will launch Safari.

```
// Check if FB app installed on device
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/355356557838717"]];
}
else {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/DanielStormApps"]];
}
```

Check out [iPhone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook) for a list of what else you can achieve via URL Schemes.

Also, starting at iOS 9 you must include `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `info.plist`.

[image]

Comment: sorry daniel but how can you know 355356557838717 this part of your url, because if i open the fb application and i go to my profile i don't find any url, where i've to look?

Comment: @kazui If its a Facebook page ID you're after make sure you're logged in as your page and navigate to the About section. The page ID should be located at the bottom. Alternatively, you can use a website like [Find My Facebook ID](https://lookup-id.com/) and find it via the pages URL.

Comment: for some reason, when I call fb://profile/<my app id> it opens the facebook app in the right page, then immediately crashes... Does this happen to anyone else?